# Send emails via mailjet with django

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

I am trying to implement a reset password functionality and I want to use the mailjet for sending an email. So far I have been using the django views fro reset password just overwriting the html files. I have set up the EMAIL_BACKEND in the settings, but I do not get emails - do I need to write separate views?

````
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset.html', html_email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html'), name ='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset_done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html'),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset_confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html'),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password_reset_complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_complete.html'),
         name='password_reset_complete'),```
````

Comment: ANYMAIL = {
    'MAILJET_API_KEY': ' ',
    'MAILJET_SECRET_KEY': ' ',
}
EMAIL_BACKEND = "anymail.backends.mailjet.EmailBackend"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "test@gmail.com"

Comment: You can use the [`sendtestemail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#sendtestemail) to check that anymail is configured correctly, before you start testing your password reset views. For example `python manage.py sendtestemail email@example.com`.

Comment: The problem might be `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "test@gmail.com"`. You may find that mailjet won't allow you to mail from that address, or require you to verify ownership of that address. Another possibility is that mailjet send the email, but it is blocked by the destination mail provider because it doesn't come from gmail servers.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair So the problem that it's not sending is the settings, and I do not need to write a custom view function for sending an email ?

Comment: The problem probably isn’t in the view - my suggestion is to use `sendtestemail` to narrow down where the problem is. An advantage of swappable email backends is to allow you to switch backends without having to rewrite your views.

Comment: @Alasdair I have tried sendtestemail - I'm still not getting an email, but there not seem to be errors as well

Comment: At least you've now confirmed that the issue isn't in your password reset views. As I said before, I think the problem might be your `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`. I would log onto mailjet and see if you can see any logs or errors about the emails you have sent. Apart from that, I don't have any suggestions because I'm not a mailjet user. Hope you manage to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

It's not sufficient to just set the Django email settings, you also need some Python glue to teach the generic Django email functionality how to talk to Mailjet. Fortunately, there are libraries for that, and in particular https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail works well for me and it includes support for Mailjet. See also longer notes on how to integrate Mailjet with Django on my blog: https://pnote.eu/notes/django-app-engine-sending-email/